# Is there a shortcut to reuse the search term of the find and replace?

Tags: substitute

I think there is a distinct possibility this question has already been asked, but I can't find it.

If I am doing something like `:s/foo/bar/g` and then I want to call that again on the next line but with `baz` instead of `bar`, is there a faster way to do that? I feel like `&baz` should work, but it does not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask for, but you can do that:

```
:s/foo/bar/g
```

And then:

```
:s//baz/g
```

You can use that because when you use `:s` the searched pattern is saved in the search register. Which you can see with `:reg /`.

---

Work in progress: You can speed up your workflow with:

```
nnoremap && :s<UP><C-F>F/cT/
```

And use it like so:

```
:s/foo/bar/g
```

and then

```
&&baz<CR>
```

Decomposing:

```
nnoremap &&         " define a new mapping
:s<UP>              " get the last :s command in the history
<C-F>               " use this command in the cmdline window
F/                  " go back to the last /
cT/                 " change back up to the last /
```

Some notes:

- This won't work if you don't have any flag
- This won't work if you don't have a substitute string
- It *should* work otherwise

(let me know if I can improve it).

Some reading:

- `:h cmdline-window`
- `:h c_CTRL-F`

Comment: That's definitely better than what I was doing before. I'll take it that unfortunately there might not be a faster way :(.

Comment: Not AFAIK, and I'm trying to create a mapping which does what you want, but out of the box I'm pretty sure you're limited to typing again the substitute expression

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @nobe4's answer, Damian Conway has two pretty interesting mappings to speed up search and replace actions. They come from [this how i vim interview](http://howivim.com/2016/damian-conway/) which is totally worth reading completely.

To quote him:

> [...] I found I was forever doing global search-and-replaces (i.e.
>   `:%s/X/Y/g<CR>`), so I eliminated the repetitious typing by stealing the
>   never-used (by me) `S` command:

```
nmap  S  :%s//g<LEFT><LEFT>
```

> Now I just need to type: SX/Y
>
> But then I started noticing how often I did a /-search for some pattern and,
>   having looked through the matches, then wanted to globally substitute all of
>   them. Even with the S mapping that was more annoying repetition: first do the
>   search: /pattern then do the replace: Spattern/replacement So I stole
>   the (also never used by me) M command for that:

```
nmap <expr>  M  ':%s/' . @/ . '//g<LEFT><LEFT>'
```

> Now it’s just: do the search: /pattern then replace all the matches:
>   Mreplacement

---

To answer your question, I guess you could slightly modify the first mapping for
something like this:

```
nmap  S  :s///g<LEFT><LEFT>
```

This way you can first make your substitution `:s/foo/bar/g`, go to the next line, hit `S` and you'll get: `:s//|/g` where `|` is the cursor, you can now type your new subsitution.